# Load articles by tag

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags, extension-request

I've had a good look round and can't find any built-in functionality to load articles by tag (similar to `mod_articles_category`, but using Joomla 3.X's built in tags as the filter.

Does anyone know if this is possible natively in Joomla (2 of the tag menu items are no use, the 3rd links to a component view but is nearly perfect!), or if there's a module that can do this?

Comment: Maybe this is something you can use: https://github.com/lasinducharith/joomla-tags-selected

Comment: Great find, will give this a shot tomorrow!

Comment: Used it, forked it, fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @johanpw's comment, I used the linked module, forked it, and brought it up to date.

Now the module can accept multiple tags, filter by content type, as well as more options for ordering / filtering etc.

Check it out at [our Github page](https://github.com/muckypuddle/joomla-tags-selected)